# Function for returning any type Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I want to have a function that will return a Type and later that Type to be used.

For example:

```
private func getType() -> Any {
    switch self.someEnum {
    case .first:
        return UInt8.self
    case .second:
        return UInt16.self
    case .third:
        return UInt32.self
    }
}
```

And then the result to be used in

```
let returnType = self.getType()
MemoryLayout<returnType>.size
```

When I use this I got this error "Cannot find type 'returnType' in scope".

Comment: Do you want to use the type variable in arbitrary contexts, or specifically just to call `MemoryLayout`?

Comment: Specifically just for MemoryLayout, so i will just accept the answer below.

Comment: There is a way to do it using Swift metadata. I can reopen this question and answer it that way if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not simplify the problem, and return a `size` from `enum` directly:

```
enum SomeEnum {
    case first
    case second
    case third
}

extension SomeEnum {
    func getSize() -> Int {
        switch self {
        case .first:
            return MemoryLayout<UInt8>.size
        case .second:
            return MemoryLayout<UInt16>.size
        case .third:
            return MemoryLayout<UInt32>.size
        }
    }
}
```

So provided you have a class with that enum, as a member, you can use it as

```
someEnum.getSize()
```